# Flash - Play movie clip once

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to make a movie clip play once upon hover, currently it repeats endlessly.

My actionscript is as follows:

```
mc.stop();
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mover);

function mover(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    mc.play();
}
```

How do I make it stop once it has finished playing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the last frame of the movieclip put a `stop()` in the Actions

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old topic, but just for reference, there's another way to do this too.

```
mc.addFrameScript(mc.totalFrames - 1, callbackFunc);

function callbackFunc()
{
    mc.stop();
}
```

This is good if you don't want to put any code in your timeline. [Here](http://www.as3dp.com/2009/09/23/a-closer-look-using-movieclipaddframescript/)'s a link for more info on the awesomeness that is `addFrameScript`.

Comment: I never knew about this command before, oh so useful. I always thought Flash should have an event for when a MovieClip reaches the end, but this is almost as good.

Comment: Absolute necessity as it's bad practice to muck-up your timeline with too much code. Which just hides it away for you to forget about later. Thanks :-D

Answer (score 1):

You can add an EventListener to the movie clip for the its EXIT_FRAME event, such that calls Stop (or GotoAndStop) if the currentFrame is the last frame.